# How to have different conditions for jobs in the same GitHub Workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to build my project whenever upon push to GitHub, and only release the build artifact on `master` branch.

Currently I am doing this logic in different workflow files:

```yaml
# build.yaml
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      # build ...
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        # upload build artifacts
```

```yaml
# release.yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      # build ...
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        # upload build artifacts
  release:
    steps:
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        # download build artifacts
      # release my artifacts ...
```

The problem is that `# build ...` will be executed twice, and the code for build is repeated in both the yaml files. I am wondering whether something like the following is possible:

```yaml
# build.yaml
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build:
    on: [push, pull_request]
    steps:
      # build ...
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        # upload build artifacts
  release:
    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - master
    steps:
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        # download build artifacts
      # release my artifacts ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if` condition to achieve the desired result.

Just specify at the desired step in the if condition, for example, to determine that an event occurred in the `master` branch:

```yaml
if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
```

Then your `.yml` file will look something like this.

```yaml
# build.yaml
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        # upload build artifacts
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - name: Conditional step
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        # download build artifacts
      # release my artifacts ...
```